# Exception: 'For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document when converting XML to XSL-FO

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xsl-fo

Below is the code I'm using for converting XML to XSL-FO

[image: CODE]

at line:8 xslt.Transform(); I'm getting this Exception

System.Xml.XmlException: 'For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the DtdProcessing property on XmlReaderSettings to Parse and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method.'

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an `XmlReader` with the right `XmlReader` settings e.g.

```
using (var xr = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\XSLT\sample.xml", new XmlReaderSettings() { DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse }))
{
  xslt.Transform(xr, null, w);
}
```